# Save pictures in .pdf, .fig, and .jpeg with different paper orientation

Tags: matlab, landscape-portrait

I want to save the same picture in different formats (.pdf, .jpeg, .fig) with diferent orientation.

Here is my current code:

```
A = readtable('RON.xlsx');
tempo_A = A{:,1:2:end}; 
[n,m] = size(A);
variavel_original = A{:,2:2:end}; 
var = {'Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4'};
guardar = {'Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4'};
guardar2 = {'YY'};
var_original = {'Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4'};
n_var = length(var); 
for j=1:n_var 
    pdf=figure;
    set(pdf,'PaperUnits','centimeters','PaperPosition',[0 0 29 21],'PaperOrientation','landscape');
    plot(tempo_A(:,j),variavel_original(:,j),'-b*'); 
    title(var(j));
    grid on
    xlabel('tempo');
    ylabel('Y');
    legend(var_original(j),'Location','best','Orientation','vertical'); 
    saveas(pdf,fullfile('C:\Users\TiagoAlexandre\Documents\MATLAB\GALP\RON\Originais', guardar{j}), 'pdf');    
end
```

So, in the `set` command I choose the option landscape, it creates a pdf file landscape of size almost A4 which is OK for the purpose.

---

Questions:

1. I wanted to save the jpeg file as 'portrait', how would I do that? (I want the jpeg file the same way as the pdf file, with the plot left to right).
2. I would want to save the .fig file a bit bigger, like a maximized window.

Comment: 1) You want the jpg rotated? Rotate the image, and then save it.... 2) a fig is a file with "code" to replot the figure. Probably best to maxmize it in after loading.

Comment: how do I rotate just the one I want to save as jpg?

Comment: `imwrite(img','mifile.jpg')`. Note he apostrophe after img

Answer (score 0):

As i posted it saves a pdf landscape, to make a landscape of a jpg file the code is the following:

```
orient portrait
saveas(pdf,fullfile('C:\Users\TiagoAlexandre\Documents\MATLA‌​B\GALP\RON\Originais‌​', guardar{j}), 'jpg');
```